# Two-Level Data Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong (if not everything in principle).

I'm trying to do a databind against something that looks like the following:

```
<infragistics:ToggleButtonTool Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Child.Item.Property, 
          Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Whenever the command is called (and updates Property), the toggle status is not reflected.

After the command is called, Child.Item.Property is changed (just the Property, not Child or Item).  I can confirm the appropriate INotifyPropertyChanged event is raised/called, as it is everywhere else in our application.

I'm curious if there is an issue with binding to a secondary level.

I've noticed that Snoop, when it hovers over something in specific to inspect it (via ctrl + shift), it will cause the toggle change to become visible and reflected in the UI.

Did I miss something?

Comment: maybe use `mode=TwoWay`?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a OneWay Binding. Remove it.

Comment: Good to know.

Property is GET only.

Comment: there is not an issue with binding to `Path=Child.Item.Property` you should look into the way `Property` is defined and make sure the path exists.

Comment: Show us the property definition, and how exactly the PropertyChanged event is fired for it.

Comment: Also put a breakpoint on the Property `get` accessor, if it doesn't get hit then there's something wrong with your binding. Bear in mind that both Child and Item also have to be properties in order for the binding to work, they can't just be fields.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the assembly.  For whatever reason, utilizing Command AND IsChecked seem to blow things up.

Answer (score 0):

I inherited the code and I was a fool.  Initially, "Child" was null.  The initial binding failed because it was null and nothing ever raised that the "Child" had changed.

TLDR - Verify EVERYTHING has a PropertyChanged appropriately in your chain.